# How do you embed a plugin in wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to embed this plugin
PB oEmbed HTML5 Audio - with Cache Support
itno a table , in a wordpress page does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Plugins->Activate your Plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you're embedding it into a post you'll need to use a shortcode, an example being:

`[audio id="your-css-id" class="pb-html5-audio-element" mp3="audio.mp3" ogg="audio.ogg" wav="audio.wav" autoplay="on" loop="on" preload="on" controls="on" flash_fallback="on"]`

If you need to put it into a theme file, then you can call this shortcode using `do_shortcode`, for example:

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[audio mp3="audio.mp3" ogg="audio.ogg" wav="audio.wav" autoplay="on" loop="on" preload="on" controls="on" flash_fallback="on"]');
?>
```

All of this, and more, is available on the [plugin's page on the WordPress plugins directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pb-oembed-html5-audio-with-cache-support/).

Comment: Hi I know about the shortcode, but the shortcode does not seem to be working then I combined them with Table. any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you have unclosed tags in your table, or you might have JavaScript errors (open your JS console by `ctrl + shift + j` in Chrome)